# What is a good way of getting a class object from the server and into a js object on initial page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Currently, I'm doing something like this in my application:

```
// Foo Controller
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return View();
}

// Foo Details View
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewBag = {
        'id': @ViewBag.id
    };// *Note: MVC will cry about a syntax error here, everything's ok though
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Foo/details.js")"></script>

// details.js
$(function(){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        'url': '/api/foo/getData/' + viewBag.id,
        'type': 'GET'
    });
    jqXHR.done(function(data){
        ...do stuff with data object...
    });
});

// Foo Api Controller
// Instantiates the data class object to be serialized and returned
```

I do this because in the `<javascript>` element, I don't want a huge JSON string of the object just hanging out in here.  Ideally, I would like to just make a single call to the Foo Controller and have it instantiate the data class object, serialize it to a JSON string, and assign it to ViewBag.dataModel or something of the sort.

And of course I can't access `@ViewBag` inside a .js file since it's a server side object.  Does anyone know of a neater way of doing this rather than having this somewhat unnecessary back and forth?

One thought was to parse the URL for the parameters but that could potentially get ugly depending on the route structure and I would still need to wait for the initial `get` of the view to get the js scripts to do all that, and still end up having to make that second call anyways.

I don't know if it's possible or not but is there a way I could dynamically generate a .js file during the view creation that could serve as a js ViewBag, add it to the page before the details.js file loads, and then be able to access it that way?  Or maybe modify the details.js file on the fly (which might not be ideal if minifying/bundling is desired)?

The desired outcome is, I'm using knockoutJS and the initial object I'm trying to pass over is the ViewModel I want to bind to the page that contains all of the initial data from the server that I want to use.  The data object I'm getting from the server is the ViewModel which I map to an observable and bind to the DOM.  The current method I'm using seems to work fine and doesn't seem to have much overhead, but if I can avoid the second call to the server on the page's initial load, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I wouldn't write dynamic information to the script tag. Instead encode your data as JSON and then write it to a hidden field.

As you are using MVC4 you will already have a reference to JSON.NET so you should be able to do this:

**In the controller**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var myModel = GetMyModelData(id);
    string modelJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product); 
    return View(modelJson);
}
```

**In the view**

```
<input type="hidden" id="model" value="@Model" />
```

**In Javascript**

```
var modelJson = $('#model').val();
var modelObj = JSON.parse(modelJson);
```

Comment: I like it.  I'm going to play with this tonight and see how this turns out.  I want to give this some time to see if anyone comes up with something better but this is looking like a really good option and if that's the general consensus, I'll give this the thumbs up answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get this working the way you set it up, and I like it better than using ViewBag, but I ended up not doing a strongly typed view of the model (which is just a string, yeah?).

Comment: I tried `@model string` for the model declaration and sent the converted JSON string as the model but got an Illegal characters exception.  I tried `@model dynamic` and `@model object` after wrapping the string in a generic object (`new { modelJSON = modelJson }`).  `ViewBag.ViewModel` with `value="@ViewBag.ViewModel"` worked.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Illegal characters in path `System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional) +10663878
   System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) +42`. How do you strongly type a view with a string? Seems like I need to create a wrapper class, `public class ViewModel { public string JSON { get; set; }`, strongly type the view with `ViewModel` and do `<input type="hidden" id="model" value="@Model.JSON" />` in which case I think `@ViewBag.JSON` would work better.